# Trying to retrieve data with axios.get() but Promise never seems to return

Tags: reactjs, redux, get, axios

Im currently trying to update a Redux reducer using a get request to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com, I can curl this site from my laptop fine but when I when I try axios.get(URL/data) from my app the data is never logged so I assume the promise never returns? I am behind a proxy but have NodeJs configured for the proxy so im not sure if I have to pass some extra data to axios related to the proxy or not to do external GET requests. Basically the app logic should unfold as follows:

```
GET Data from site with axios and is logged in firefox web console->reducer is passed payload from GET-> reducer fills each object in data into an array->View updated listing all objects in array on screen with the .map function.
```

Here is the reducer below that GETs the data and updated the store:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { SUCCESS } from 'app/shared/reducers/action-type.util';

export const ACTION_TYPES = {
  GET_APP_COMMENTS: 'applicationComments/GET_COMMENTS'
};

const initialState = {
  postId: 1,
  id: 1,
  name: 'testname',
  email: 'testemail',
  body: 'body'
};

export type ApplicationCommentsState = Readonly<typeof initialState>;

    export default (state: ApplicationCommentsState = initialState, action): ApplicationCommentsState => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case SUCCESS(ACTION_TYPES.GET_APP_COMMENTS):
          const { data } = action.payload;
          return {
            ...state,
            postId: data.postId,
            id: data.id,
            name: data.name,
            email: data.email,
            body: data.body
          };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };

    export const getComments = () => ({
      type: ACTION_TYPES.GET_APP_COMMENTS,
      payload: axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
      .then(res => {
        console.log('got here' + res);
      })
    });
```

I set up this reducer in the Redux index.js file where I combine all reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { loadingBarReducer as loadingBar } from 'react-redux-loading-bar';

import authentication, { AuthenticationState } from './authentication';
import applicationProfile, { ApplicationProfileState } from './application-profile';
import applicationComments, { ApplicationCommentsState } from './application-comments'; // Is this the correct way to import the comments reducer?

import administration, { AdministrationState } from 'app/modules/administration/administration.reducer';
import userManagement, { UserManagementState } from 'app/modules/administration/user-management/user-management.reducer';
import register, { RegisterState } from 'app/modules/account/register/register.reducer';
import activate, { ActivateState } from 'app/modules/account/activate/activate.reducer';
import password, { PasswordState } from 'app/modules/account/password/password.reducer';
import settings, { SettingsState } from 'app/modules/account/settings/settings.reducer';
import passwordReset, { PasswordResetState } from 'app/modules/account/password-reset/password-reset.reducer';

export interface IRootState {
  readonly authentication: AuthenticationState;
  readonly applicationProfile: ApplicationProfileState;
  readonly applicationComments: ApplicationCommentsState;
  readonly administration: AdministrationState;
  readonly userManagement: UserManagementState;
  readonly register: RegisterState;
  readonly activate: ActivateState;
  readonly passwordReset: PasswordResetState;
  readonly password: PasswordState;
  readonly settings: SettingsState;
  /* jhipster-needle-add-reducer-type - JHipster will add reducer type here */
  readonly loadingBar: any;
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers<IRootState>({
  authentication,
  applicationProfile,
  applicationComments,
  administration,
  userManagement,
  register,
  activate,
  passwordReset,
  password,
  settings,
  /* jhipster-needle-add-reducer-combine - JHipster will add reducer here */
  loadingBar
});

export default rootReducer;
```

I call the getComments method that has been passed as a prop in the following component, this should trigger the console.log but it doesn't and the component just renders anyway:

```
import './appView.css';

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CommentsSection } from './appView-componets';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';

import { getSession } from 'app/shared/reducers/authentication';
import { getComments } from 'app/shared/reducers/application-comments';

export interface IAppViewState {
  dropdownOpen: boolean;
}

export interface IAppViewProp extends StateProps, DispatchProps, IAppViewState {}

export class AppView extends React.Component<IAppViewProp> {
  state: IAppViewState = {
    dropdownOpen: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getSession();
    this.props.getComments();
  }

  toggleCatagories = () => {
    this.setState({ dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen });
  };

  render() {
    const comments = this.props;
    console.log('comments: ' + comments);
    return (
      <div>
        <CommentsSection comments={comments} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = storeState => ({
  account: storeState.authentication.account,
  isAuthenticated: storeState.authentication.isAuthenticated,
  comments: storeState.applicationComments.comments
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { getSession, getComments };

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AppView);
```

Comment: Are you using any middleware for async actions? Redux Thunk or Sagas?

Comment: Yes thunk is used

Comment: Using `redux thunk` you should refactor `getComments()` into a thunk that receives `dispatch` as an argument, does the async fetch and then dispatches a pure action with the results.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the request in my app and it seems to work fine. I'm not sure you have your action set up correctly to use the thunk middleware. Maybe give this a try.

```
export const getCommentSuccess = (comments) => {
    return {
        type: ACTION_TYPES.GET_APP_COMMENTS,
        comments
    }
}

export const getComments = () => {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments').then(response => {
            console.log(response) //This should be the returned comments
            dispatch(getCommentSuccess(response));
        }).catch(error => {
            throw(error);
        });
    };
```

And make sure your middleware is imported properly in your store.

```
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, 
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware
    )
);
```

Comment: Great answer man. I think using thunks, like `redux-thunk` is the best way to handle async actions

Answer (score 0):

There are redux capable libraries like RxJs (Observables), Redux Saga, Redux Thunk and others which are integrated with Redux and they can be used to process actions and talk to backend combined with axios too. If you want to use just axios (which is a library for making direct calls to server) you have to wrap the call so that you first dispatch ex. GET_COMMENTS_START action with no payload (maybe url) and inside reducer you make call to server using axios. When axios promise is resolved then you should fire another action like GET_COMMENTS_SUCCESS which will then return data which will be your wanted payload and then you can retrieve it through props.
This approach might work but you should use redux specific libraries like ReduxThunk or RxJs because code is much more consistent and maintainable.
Useful links :

1. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/
2. https://redux-saga.js.org/
3. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk